# Lan chat design

Tags: sockets, lan

I'm in the process of trying to write a chat application and I have a few issues 
that I trying to work out. The application is basically a chat application that works on a Lan. One client acts as the
host and other clients can connect to the host and publicly chat among themselves. I want also the option of a client starting 
a private chat with an already connected client. So what is the best way for this to happen. For example should the request message (which 
contains  the ip address of client) route through the host and then if the requested client wants to connect , then they initiate the connection
using ip of the requesting client. Should this also be on a separate port number. Does it matter if your application uses a number of ports.

Or, when ever a client connects to a host, the host should send them a list of users with there ip addresses, and then the client can 
attempt a connection with the other client for a private chat.

Hope this all makes sense. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in a quick-and-dirty chat facility that only needs to work over a LAN, I'd suggest having all clients send and receive broadcast UDP packets on a single well-known port number.  Then no server is necessary at all, and thus no discovery is necessary either, and things are a lot simpler.

If you really want to go the client-server route, though, you should have your server (aka host) machine accept TCP connections on a single well-known port, and then have it use select() or poll() to multiplex the incoming TCP connections and forward any data that comes in from each incoming TCP socket to all of the others sockets.  Clients can connect via TCP to the server at this well-known port, but the clients will have to have some way of knowing what IP address to connect to... either from having the user type in the IP address of the server, or by some discovery mechanism (broadcast UDP packets could be used to implement that).  This way is a lot more work though.

Comment: I'm going down the route of tcp. I have my server broadcasting already using UDP so client can connect with the information. Its the private chat parts that Im finding hard to grasp. I have different ideas,like having each client listen for udp packet for a private chat. Is it bad for an application to use a number of ports at a time or doesn't it really matter

Comment: Using multiple ports is fine; the only potential issue is that if someone has a firewall that is blocking incoming packets or connections and they need to set up firewall-exceptions to allow them so your app will work, then they will have to set up multiple exceptions (one for each port) instead of just a single one.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner: I am interested in quick and dirty chat in LAN. As you have mentioned there is no need to use any server, can you please tell how it is possible? I mean some sample code which represents it..

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for creating my own but depending on time constraints sometimes I look for alternatives like [this](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) I used it in a company I worked at before. It's really good.  But if you decide to make your own you first have to map out a logic, structure, Database and so on before you even think about code..

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply. I'm trying to learn how to do it for myself.